# Print blocks in sfml

Tags: java, swing, import, sfml, jsfml

I'm doing a program in java, and I want pass at the new window when I click the button but when I run the program it automatically open me the 2 views also if I don't press the button.What can I do for fix this problem?

Main:

```
package com.SimplyGeometry.src.tiles;

import com.SimplyGeometry.src.windows.SelectWindow;
import com.SimplyGeometry.src.windows.StartWindow;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String title = "SimplyGeometry";
        int WIDTH = 1320, HEIGHT = 840;
        StartWindow stw = new StartWindow(/*WIDTH, HEIGHT, title*/);
    }

}
```

Vew1:

```
package com.SimplyGeometry.src.windows;


import javax.swing.*;

import Actions.Actions;


public class StartWindow implements ActionListener {

    public static JFrame window;
    SelectWindow sw;

    public StartWindow(/*int WIDTH, int HEIGHT, String title*/) {

        window = new JFrame("SimplyGeometry");
        window.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1320, 840));
        window.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(1320, 840));
        window.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1320, 840));
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setResizable(false);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(null);
        panel.setBounds(0, 0, 1320, 840);
        panel.setBackground(Color.CYAN);

        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        label.setIcon(new ImageIcon("/Users/gaetanodonnarumma/Documents/workspace/SimplyGeometry(Complete)/src/Images/titolo.png"));
        label.setSize(650, 250);
        label.setLocation(320, 100);

        JButton button = new JButton("Start");
        button.setBackground(Color.white);
        button.setForeground(Color.black);
        button.setSize(350, 100);
        button.setLocation(455, 450);
        button.setEnabled(true);
        button.addActionListener(new Actions());

        window.add(panel);
        panel.add(label);
        window.validate();
        panel.add(button);

        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

View 2:

```
package com.SimplyGeometry.src.windows;

import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.*;

public class SelectWindow {

    public static JFrame window;

    public SelectWindow(/*int WIDTH, int HEIGHT, String title*/) {
        window = new JFrame("SimplyGeometry");
        window.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1320, 840));
        window.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(1320, 840));
        window.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1320, 840));
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setLayout(null);

        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

}
```

the actionListener class:

```
package Actions;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import com.SimplyGeometry.src.windows.SelectWindow;
import com.SimplyGeometry.src.windows.StartWindow;

public class Actions implements ActionListener {

    public Actions() {
        SelectWindow window = new SelectWindow();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is happening because of the line below:

```
public StartWindow(
    ...
    button.addActionListener(new Actions());
    ...
}
```

In the constructor of the `Actions`, `SelectWindow` is creating. So it is coming to the screen after you create `StartWindow`.

```
public Actions() {
    SelectWindow window = new SelectWindow();
}
```

To solve the problem create `SelectWindow` in `actionPerformed`.

```
public class Actions implements ActionListener {

    public Actions() {
        //SelectWindow window = new SelectWindow();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        SelectWindow window = new SelectWindow();
    }

}
```